# Error on running integration tests while building hono from source - certificate expired

Tags: eclipse-hono

I followed the steps for building hono from source from this page `https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/dev-guide/building_hono/`

The build completes without errors, but when running the integration tests, I receive lots of errors related to timeouts and expired certificates. Here's an excerpt of the log:

```
HTTP11:59:07.040 [main] INFO  o.e.h.adapter.http.impl.Application - The following profiles are active: prod
ARTEMIS2020-10-29 11:59:09,455 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking with /172.19.0.5:38356 has occurred.
QPID2020-10-29 11:59:09.827479 +0000 SERVER (info) [C4] Connection to hono-artemis.hono:5671 failed: amqp:connection:framing-error SSL Failure: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Is it possible to update the certificates or is this not the main problem?
[Here's the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_E1oCZb9mm15ltdiC-XOJxZ_hHdM2bZ/view?usp=sharing) to the complete log file

Answer (score 1):

You are probably building sources from one of the previously released tags, i.e. not from the master branch, right?

If so, the demo certificates included in the source code may have expired in the meantime since the time of release. You can re-create the certificates by running the `demo-certs/create_certs.sh` script. Note that this needs to be done once only, i.e. it is not necessary to do this before each build.